# .NET CF 3.5 build, how do I find which bug or fixes it includes?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm running an application on Window CE 6.0 and I have .NET CF 3.5.7283 (I know this by running cgacutil.exe)

I have an issue where I see an article on MS site at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979447

I am trying to find out if the issue in this KB is fixed under build 7283, but I can't seem to find a list of fixes issue that comes with that build... do you know a link to resources that indicates what is the latest .NET CF 3.5 build and what bugs/fixes that build include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CF version table on Wikipedia puts 3.5.7283 (it was SP1 IIRC) with a release date of January 2008.  The KB fix you mention didn't happen until January 2010, so I'd say it's a safe bet you do not have the fix.  I'm guessing you need at least 3.5.10181 which would be in the 2010 QFE rollup for CE 6.0.  3.5.11125 would be in [the 2011 QFE rollup](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=28753).